# React DatePicker - How to call custom function on date select?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, date, datepicker

In react, I am trying to add a search feature based on date selection. I have referred and using https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker.

```
function Result(props) {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());

  return(
   <div>
     <DatePicker onChange={onChange} value={value} />
   </div>
  );
}
```

My other class component,

```
handleOnClick = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
}

<Result handleOnclick={this.handleOnclick} />
```

Now I want to call my own function `handleOnclick` as soon as date has been selected by passing the value(date).
In my custom function I should be able to fetch the selected date.

Dependencies are,

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-date-picker": "^8.0.3",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.0",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
```

How can I achieve this changes? Please help me.

Comment: The onChange prop will accept a function which would be called with the new date

Comment: onChange={(date) => { onchange(date); also whatever you want}}

Comment: But date will not get updated to the input field if I use  `onChange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a custom function to the onChange prop and update the state from there. and carry out your custom logic there.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';
    
function Result(props) {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());

  const onDateChange=(newDate)=>{
   //Your custom code here
   props.handleOnclick(newDate);
   onChange(newDate);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onDateChange}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The other option is to use the useEffect and add the value as a dependency which will run when the value is changed.

```
useEffect(()=>{
//your custom code here
},[value]);
```

Comment: While returning `onChange(newDate);` from a function, I am getting `'onChange' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: So your function is outside this component ?

Comment: If its outside the component, you will have to pass the onChange function to it or have a function like above and call the other function from the onDateChange

Comment: How to make value = " " by default ? Right now its taking current date as default. I want an empty text box initially later it can be filled with selected value.

Comment: If you dont pass anything then blank is displayed

Comment: Or even null will work, when you press the clear button it sets to null

Comment: In both cases, even after date selection it will be empty. But I want a selected date in text field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224416/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-shruthi-r).